# Copy Files Step in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, data-integration

I have a job that uses the copy files step which copies files from an authenticated server to another windows server. When I run the job from my local it seems to run fine, but when I place the job into the server and run it, there is an error thrown.

```
The File/Folder source is \\Folder\IlogB\2014-05-21\u_ex14052018_2014-05-21 03 00 02.log
The File/Folder destination is ftp://1c4:1c4@10.124.56.88/1CAAP/1413/data/

Unexpected error : java.io.FileNotFoundException: (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Any ideas as to how I can make the job run when placed on the server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not an error message. Could you check the contents of the log file mentioned in the message? Maybe you'll find an error message there...

Comment: Is this error related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24303958/copy-files-step-not-working-when-placed-in-server?

Comment: Hi, Yes that's not an error message I just mentioned the source and destination I used.

Comment: Hi, Yes they're the same question one of my associates must have posted the same using another account. sorry about that.

Comment: Please, delete one of them, then.

Comment: Deleted. I have included the error in the question.

Comment: Have you tried to use a filename without spaces?

Comment: Yes the filename is without spaces only. The issue I believe is that Pentaho is unable to access the source server without me moving the job to my local where I have already given access credentials. I need to find a step that enables me to give pentaho the access credentials directly. Any step that can help me do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your local system wouldn't by any chance be a Windows machine while your remote server is running Linux or any flavor of Unix, would it? My first suspect are those back slashes that should be  forward slashes.